# C program to limit the count of characters entered by user. Need Solution?

Tags: c

I am getting space between input array and output array, WHY?

```
[#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    char str\[99999\];

    scanf(" %d", &i);
    for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &str\[j\]);
    }
    for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        printf("%c", str\[j\]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

3

harsh

```
                                     //Why This Space??
```

har

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are processing **4** characters with indices 0,1,2,3.

Your input characters are : <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

The first `scanf("% d",...)` read only the `3` and leaves the other characters in the input buffer then you read the **4** characters  `\n`, `h`, `a`, `r`... and print a new line followed with `har`